# x86-64 Bit Assembly Linux Input

Tags: linux, assembly, 64-bit, x86-64

I'm trying to input into my program...  All it does is run through and print a '0' to the screen. I'm pretty sure that the PRINTDECI function works, I made it a while ago and it works. Do I just have to loop over the input code and only exit when I enter a certain value? I'm not sure how I would do that...  Unless it's by ACSII values which might suck.... Anyways, here's my code (Yasm(nasm clone), Intel Syntax):

```
GLOBAL _start
SECTION .text

PRINTDECI:
 LEA R9,[NUMBER + 18]       ; last character of buffer
 MOV R10,R9                 ; copy the last character address
 MOV RBX,10                 ; base10 divisor

 DIV_BY_10:

 XOR RDX,RDX                ; zero rdx for div
 DIV RBX                    ; rax:rdx = rax / rbx
 ADD RDX,0x30               ; convert binary digit to ascii
 TEST RAX,RAX               ; if rax == 0 exit DIV_BY_10
 JZ CHECK_BUFFER
 MOV byte [R9],DL           ; save remainder
 SUB R9,1                   ; decrement the buffer address
 JMP DIV_BY_10

 CHECK_BUFFER:

 MOV byte [R9],DL
 SUB R9,1

 CMP R9,R10                 ; if the buffer has data print it
 JNE PRINT_BUFFER 
 MOV byte [R9],'0'          ; place the default zero into the empty buffer
 SUB R9,1

 PRINT_BUFFER:

 ADD R9,1                   ; address of last digit saved to buffer
 SUB R10,R9                 ; end address minus start address
 ADD R10,1                  ; R10 = length of number
 MOV RAX,1                  ; NR_write
 MOV RDI,1                  ; stdout
 MOV RSI,R9                 ; number buffer address
 MOV RDX,R10                ; string length
 SYSCALL
RET

_start:
 MOV RCX, SCORE     ;Input into Score
 MOV RDX, SCORELEN
 MOV RAX, 3
 MOV RBX, 0
 SYSCALL

 MOV RAX, [SCORE]
 PUSH RAX           ;Print Score
  CALL PRINTDECI
 POP RAX

 MOV RAX,60         ;Kill the Code
 MOV RDI,0
 SYSCALL

SECTION .bss
 SCORE:         RESQ 1
 SCORELEN EQU $-SCORE
```

Thanks for any help!
 - Kyle

As a side note, the pointer in RCX goes to a insanely large number according to DDD...  So I'm thinking I have to get it to pause and wait for me to type, but I have no idea how to do that...

Comment: Shouldn't you be using [`RAX`=0 as sys_read](http://blog.rchapman.org/post/36801038863/linux-system-call-table-for-x86-64) in 64-bit mode? The other parameters also appear to be in the wrong registers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'setup' to call `syscall 0` (READ) on x86_64 system is:

```
@xenon:~$ syscalls_lookup read
read:
        rax = 0  (0x0)
        rdi = unsigned int fd
        rsi = char *buf
        rdx = size_t count
```

So your `_start` code should be something like:

```
_start:
    mov  rax, 0         ; READ
    mov  rdi, 0         ; stdin
    mov  rsi, SCORE     ; buffer
    mov  rdx, SCORELEN  ; length
    syscall
```

The register conventions and syscall numbers for x86_64 are **COMPLETELY** different than those for i386.

Some conceptual issues you seem to have:

- READ does not do ANY interpretation on what you type, you seem to be expecting it to let you type a number (say, 57) and have it return the value 57.  Nope.  It'll return '5', '7', 'ENTER', 'GARBAGE'...  Your SCORELEN is probably 8 (length of resq 1), so you'll read, AT MOST, 8 bytes.  or Characters, if you wish to call them that.  And unless you type the EOF char (^D), you'll need to type those 8 characters before the READ call will return to your code.
- You have to convert the *characters* you receive into a value... You can do it the easy way and link with ATOI() in the C library, or write your own parser to convert the *characters* into a value by addition and multiplication (it's not hard, see code below).

Used below, here as a reference:

```
@xenon:~$ syscalls_lookup write
write:
        rax = 1  (0x1)
        rdi = unsigned int fd
        rsi = const char *buf
        rdx = size_t count
```

Ugh.... So many...  I'll just rewrite bits:

```
    global _start
    section .text

PRINTDECI:
; input is in RAX
    lea  r9, [NUMBER + NUMBERLEN - 1 ]  ; + space for \n
    mov  r10, r9            ; save end position for later
    mov  [r9], '\n'         ; store \n at end
    dec  r9
    mov  rbx, 10            ; base10 divisor

DIV_BY_10:
    xor  rdx, rdx       ; zero rdx for div
    div  rbx            : rax = rdx:rax / rbx, rdx = remainder
    or   dl, 0x30       ; make REMAINDER a digit
    mov  [r9], dl
    dec  r9
    or   rax, rax
    jnz  DIV_BY_10

PRINT_BUFFER:
    sub  r10, r9        ; get length (r10 - r9)
    inc  r9             ; make r9 point to initial character
    mov  rax, 1         ; WRITE (1)
    mov  rdi, 1         ; stdout
    mov  rsi, r9        ; first character in buffer
    mov  rdx, r10       ; length
    syscall
    ret

MAKEVALUE:
; RAX points to buffer
    mov  r9, rax        ; save pointer
    xor  rcx, rcx       ; zero value storage

MAKELOOP:
    mov  al, [r9]       ; get a character
    or   al, al         ; set flags
    jz   MAKEDONE       ; zero byte? we're done!
    and  rax, 0x0f      ; strip off high nybble and zero rest of RAX (we're lazy!)
    add  rcx, rcx       ; value = value * 2
    mov  rdx, rcx       ; save it
    add  rcx, rcx       ; value = value * 4
    add  rcx, rcx       ; value = value * 8
    add  rcx, rdx       ; value = value * 8 + value * 2 (== value * 10)
    add  rcx, rax       ; add new digit
    jmp  MAKELOOP       ; do it again

MAKEDONE:
    mov  rax, rcx       ; put value in RAX to return
    ret

_start:
    mov  rax, 0         ; READ (0)
    mov  rdi, 0         ; stdin
    mov  rsi, SCORE     ; buffer
    mov  rdx, SCORELEN  ; length
    syscall

; RAX contains HOW MANY CHARS we read!
; -OR-, -1 to indicate error, really
; should check for that, but that's for
; you to do later... right? (if RAX==-1,
; you'll get a segfault, just so you know!)

    add  rax, SCORE     ; get position of last byte
    movb [rax], 0       ; force a terminator at end

    mov  rax, SCORE     ; point to beginning of buffer
    call MAKEVALUE      ; convert from ASCII to a value

; RAX now should have the VALUE of the string of characters
; we input above. (well, hopefully, right?)

    mov  [VALUE], rax   ; store it, because we can!

; it's stored... pretend it's later... we need value of VALUE!

    mov  rax, [VALUE]   ; get the VALUE
    call PRINTDECI      ; convert and display value

; all done!
    mov  rax, 60        ; EXIT (60/0x3C)
    mov  rdi, 0         ; exit code = 0
    syscall

    section .bss
SCORE:  resb 11   ; 10 chars + zero terminator
SCORELEN equ $-SCORE
NUMBER: resb 19   ; 18 chars + CR terminator
NUMBERLEN equ $-NUMBER
```

I'm going to say that this **should** work first time, it's off-the-cuff for me, haven't tested it, but it should be good.  We read up to 10 chars, terminate it with a zero, convert to a value, then convert to ascii and write it out.

To be more proper, you should save registers to the stack in each subroutine, well, certain ones, and really, only if you're going to interface with libraries... doing things yourself lets you have all the freedom you want to play with the registers, you just have to remember what you put where!

Yes, someone is going to say "why didn't you just multiply by 10 instead of weird adding?" ... uh... because it's easier on the registers and I don't have to set it all up in rdx:rax.  Besides, it's just as readable and understandable, especially with the comments.  Roll with it!  This isn't a competition, it's learning!

Machine code is fun! Gotta juggle all the eggs in your head though... no help from the compiler here!

Technically, you should check return result (RAX) of the syscalls for READ and WRITE, handle errors appropriately, yadda yadda yadda.... learn to use your debugger (gdb or whatever).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I really should have checked if character was a digit in MAKEVALUE.  entering '5', '7', 'ENTER' is probably going to compute 5 * 100 + 7 * 10 + 10 (the enter is a \n or 0x0a value).  Hmmm.  Exercise for the student?

Comment: Thank you!  This is just the answer I was looking for!  Would you happen to know of a good reference for the Linux system calls?  Thank you!

Comment: [Linux SysCall Reference](http://syscalls.kernelgrok.com/) is a decent reference, try searching for `linux syscall list` or similar.  Remember, get the proper one!  `i386` syscalls are totally different from `x86_64` syscalls.  If you email me, I have some references I've compiled to help that I can share. (e.g. the 'syscall_lookup' function, above)